# application completely SOA?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, soa, architecture

Is it wise to build a large application entirely based off SOA? Or just some portions? User account logins, accounting, gis mapping, sales, etc?

In other words, would it be wise to build a GUI to such an application in HTML & Javascript which does all it's exchanges via ajax to .NET web services on the back-end?

I can't see it worth loosing all the .net .aspx functionality such as forms authentication, view state, etc. But my co-worker is saying if we are going to go SOA there is no need for .NET on the front end. But i think there should be some sort of balance. Where do you draw the line? Should all calls to the database go through the web services?

Comment: You could both lookup the acronym and see if you agree about what it actually means.  Bounce it back-and-forth, see if any *real* ideas pop out beyond the three letters.  Then do what make sense to both of you.  If your co-worker just keeps going about the letters then look for another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the words of the song 'If I had a hammer' coming to mind. [SOA is an architectural approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969964/when-to-use-soa-service-oriented-architecture) to develop software as a series of services. In my opinion this is best for systems that have less than immediate latency and limited bandwidth, and high cost in access etc (these are all obviously highly subjective). You don't need full SOA just get loose couping between components which I would argue is a good goal to achieve.

DB calls can go through a service, take ADO.NET data services for example however you really have to weigh up with what the service is to provide. Take caching. A decent approach to SOA will consider that data is may need to be cached to reduce service load. So can your data be stale in the UI? Are you allowing that use case? Is right for login info to be stale (a rough example I know but possibly something that *may* need to be addressed).

All in all - it depends. I think some things lend themselves to SOA very well. If you take a [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) approach then the services that represent Domains would probably do so. In this way your UI talks to domain services and not rows in table as the DB is abstracted behind domain services.

**Don't use one methodology to solve all problems.**

See this [SO question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) too

Answer (score 2):

I just want to say that "with SOA we’re building for change, while with Traditional systems engineering, we’re building for stability."

The problem with stability, of course, is, it only takes the business so far — if the organization requires business agility, then they’re much better off implementing SOA.

So, It solely depends on what you want to achieve, you are the one who should draw the boundary.

I read it in article on SOA few days back as I'm too working on SOA.

---

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile I came across [this](http://hubpages.com/hub/soa-with-wcf) article and thought of sharing with you.
The video quite explains the current scenario of SOA and its views by different people.

Answer (score 1):

It's a service oriented architecture, not a service exclusive architecture.

Presentation logic and plumbing have to live somewhere; it all depends on where it makes the most sense for it to live.

For example, let's say you have a UI component that relies on a highly chatty but efficient set of calls to a database to generate a complex analysis of something (take your pick). If your web browser is making all those calls, you introduce massive network latency and concurrency issues. If a web service makes all those calls, you are potentially putting presentation logic into it to format that result.

If you are using Session state (or web services period), you are essentially using ASP.Net anyway. Try uninstalling it and see if your web services still run.

If presentation logic needs to live on the server side, it is better for it to live within a framework intended for presentation rather than a web service, IMO.  If you haven't looked at MVC 2, do so. It makes it incredibly easy to set up an application that melds browser and server UI support (for example, jQuery validator controls backed by server-side validation).

Conversely, the web browser provides an expressive platform. Assuming browser support and team knowledge, the AJAX/SOA architecture you describe is a good one. I'm using it more and more and trying to make my server pages cleaner and simpler but I have no plans to exclude ASP.Net from my toolkit any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Client implementation should be completely disconnected from the back end web service in a SOA.  The service should be able to be consumed by ANY client.  If you are using .NET on the back end and front end because they can be coded to directly communicate, then you are missing the point, because now they are tightly coupled and what you have now is a stove pipe application.  The client should have no idea how the server side is implemented -- shouldn't matter if the back-end web service is built using .NET, Java, or whatever.

In a true SOA, you should be able to search for services in the services repository, perhaps tie the outputs in with other services or use XSLT to create alternative outputs that weren't necessarily considered when the original service was built, and consume it in a standard way in any client on the front end.

It sounds like what you're really asking is how to build a single application.  The point of a SOA is to provide standard data sets through re-usable interfaces, that have no specific application or implementation in mind.  To start out building a single application with the entire back-end comprised of SOA services would be a huge undertaking.  In *MY* mind, each back-end service should be built because of it's intrinsic value all on it's own and be provided to the entire SOA "domain".  Then when you or I decide to make a client that does X, Y, and Z, we can just go find those capabilities in the SOA and injest them.