# Node Web App with Java API

Tags: java, javascript, git, node.js, tomcat

Here is the story;

We recently started a project with 1 FE guy experienced in Node environment and 2 BE guy working with Java.

We built the BE of it, the API side on Tomcat + Java and the actual web app part running on node.js/express.js. So, the www (web app) part of it runs on express.js and makes ajax calls to the Tomcat Server to return json results.

As we had full time jobs and limited time to sit down and talk about things, this seemed to be a fast way to get the project up and running.

The thing is that, you have two separate projects, to git pushes and two instances running on amazon.

Right now, we are stuck in a discussion where this architecture makes sense or not. So we need an expert to put an end to this argument.

Thanks

Comment: From your description, I don't really see the point of having the Node app, since the tomcat is already returning json. Are you using NodeJS solely for rendering html?

Comment: Yes, its only to render html and think it I just wanted hear if there was any condition that it made sense before ripping things apart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reads as though you're recreating a [Service Oriented Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture#Benefits)

> Service-oriented architecture (SOA) is a software design and software architecture design pattern based on discrete pieces of software that provide application functionality as services, known as Service-orientation.

It's hard to give a informed answer in your instance without more information on the context. But there are dozens of posts on SO and elsewhere which can guide your discussion on when it is the right approach. Try [What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Services over Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973673/what-is-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-services-over-components) and [When to use SOA Service Oriented Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969964/when-to-use-soa-service-oriented-architecture)